# Using a REGEX with SQL

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress

I've got a custom searchable member page on a WordPress site running s2member and I have a client that wants to use the mutli select box feature for the "category" data listed members can enter. My current code falls down here as the REGEX I currently use to select the category from the meta_value field only works with the single select box.

Here is the data as it appears in the database field:

s:8:"category";a:1:{i:0;s:17:"Business services";}}

Here is my current AND line in my SQL statement:

AND UMS.meta_value REGEXP '.*\"".$_SESSION['searchfield']."\";s:[0-9]+:\".*".$_SESSION['searchvar'].".*\".*'

How can I modify the above REGEX to work with the new multi option data? I’ve tried a few things but REGEX isn't a strong point of mine.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your database design seems to be... subpar.

Comment: I would tend to agree with Klas here, you seem to be storing far to much information in a single field.  Is changing your DB schema an option?